# Is it possible to check the time taken by a Salesforce Record to load when we we view/open the record?

Tags: performance, architecture

Can i find the time taken by my record page to load in Salesforce Dev Console.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on lightning, there's some documented steps you can take:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-experience-performance-optimization/measure-lightning-experience-performance-and-experience-page-time-ept

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kris, I will be able to play on platform to check performance.

Comment: Is there anything for classic ?

Comment: For classic, I'd just use the debug console in your browser. In Chrome --> F12 --> Select "network" and reload the page.